# Make all form controls read-only in template-based form

Tags: forms, angular

We have a template-based form that uses the various Angular Material controls (matInput, mat-select, etc).  We want to create a 'read-only' type view for some users. My immediate thought was to simply check a user's privileges and then loop through all form controls and set them to disable if need be.

This appears to work for text input type controls but is not working for selects and checkboxes.  Plus this grays-out the controls which isn't necessarily what we want.

Any ideas on how to best accomplish this?  Perhaps somehow disable keyboard and mouse input within the form might be what we want but I have no idea how to go about this.

Comment: Do _not_ attempt to disable input. You have the write idea but you need to do a bit more work to make selects and radios work. Try `*ngIf` and rendering a different control based on the state of the form. As for how it looks, that can be tweaked.

Comment: The problem is our forms are very complex and can have NUMEROUS properties.  It's unrealistic to manually build out conditionals for every single control.  I need a generic approach that can be applied to any form with any number of controls and control types.

Comment: My advice would be to wrap each control in a component that exposes a higher-level API. For example you can expose a `readonly` property, a `model` property, and an `input-type` property.

Comment: That said, I recommend you take a look at something like ng2formly.

Comment: @AluanHaddad You say 'do not attempt to disable input'.  Why is this?

Comment: I meant the user's keyboard and mouse as mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible, but you will have to check all control types, for example `MatInput` exposes `readonly` property, it allows us to create simple directive which will switch `readonly` state for entire form:

```
import {Directive, ContentChildren, QueryList, AfterContentInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {NgModel} from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: 'form[readonly]'
})
export class FormReadonlyDirective implements AfterContentInit
{
    @ContentChildren(NgModel)
    public inputs:QueryList<NgModel>;

    private controls:any[];

    private _readonly:boolean = false;

    public ngAfterContentInit():void
    {
        this.controls = this.getControls();

        this.inputs.changes.subscribe(() =>
        {
            this.setReadonly(this.readonly);
        });

        this.setReadonly(this.readonly);
    }

    @Input()
    public get readonly():boolean
    {
        return this._readonly;
    }

    public set readonly(value:boolean)
    {
        this._readonly = value != null && value !== false && `${value}` !== 'false';
        this.setReadonly(value);
    }

    private setReadonly(value:boolean):void
    {
        if(this.controls != null)
        {
            this.controls.forEach(control =>
            {
                //todo: check
                control.readonly = value;
            });
        }
    }

    private getControls():any[]
    {
        return this.inputs.map(control => control.valueAccessor);
    }
}
```

Not tested, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The problem, I'm now realizing, is that our form is itself a component with contains a <ng-content> where the consumer of the form component then plops in the controls.  But in theory you could potentially have nested forms.  I need to, somehow, communicate the disabled state of the parent form to its respective children.

Comment: `ContentChildren` probably will not work with `ng-content` unfortunately, so you will have to use workaround...